# Adding borders to an entire row in a table

Tags: tables, color, rules

I have a table with multiple rows (a regression table).  I would like to add a coloured border highlighting one particular variable.  I have found a way to border one cell at a time but is there a way to add a border around an entire row?

EDIT: Here is some detail on my table:

```
\begin{tabular}{rcccccccc|cccccccc}

       &                                                       \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 1} &                                                           \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 2} \\

       &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

       &        (1) &        (2) &        (3) &        (4) &        (5) &        (6) &        (7) &        (8) &        (9) &       (10) &       (11) &       (12) &       (13) &       (14) &       (15) &       (16) \\

       &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

regression coef 1 &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &             no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no \\

       &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

regression coef 2 & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} & {\bf 1234} &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

       & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} & {\bf [2]} &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: which row would you like to highlight?

Comment: how about regression coef 2

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I would suggest using `\begin{tabular}{r*8c|*8c}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{rcccccccc|cccccccc}`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: nevermind, it's `\begin{tabular}{r*{8}{c}}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\tikzmark` to place some marks at the desired locations and then draw the frame using the marks; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{rcccccccc|cccccccc}
& \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 1} & \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 2} \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
&        (1) &        (2) &        (3) &        (4) &        (5) &        (6) &        (7) &        (8) &        (9) &       (10) &       (11) &       (12) &       (13) &       (14) &       (15) &       (16) \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
regression coef 1 &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &             no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
\tikzmark{a}regression coef 2 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &  \\
& \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] &            &            &            &            &            &            &            & \phantom{noo}\tikzmark{b} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=1pt,draw=orange!70!black,rounded corners=4pt]
 ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=7pt]a.north) rectangle ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-5pt]b.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs two runs to stabilize.

As a side note, `\bf` is a deprecated command; you should use `\bfseries` instead. Also, the table cells define groups so you don't need to explicitly group using braces.

Comment: when i do this i get the following error:  LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

Comment: @Alex simply load `xcolor` *before* `tikz`.

Comment: Ahh ok, let me give that a try.  I am very new to latex, could you explain to me what that error means?

Comment: @Alex of course, `tikz` internally loads `xcolor` *without* options; attempting to load `xcolor` with options after `tikz` will trigger the error you mentioned; the solution is just to load `xcolor` with options before `tikz`.

Answer (score 4):

You can get fancier borders using `tikz` but the classic way is to us `\hline`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{rcccccccc|cccccccc}
& \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 1} & \multicolumn{ 8}{c}{section 2} \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
&        (1) &        (2) &        (3) &        (4) &        (5) &        (6) &        (7) &        (8) &        (9) &       (10) &       (11) &       (12) &       (13) &       (14) &       (15) &       (16) \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
regression coef 1 &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &             no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r}{regression coef 2 }& \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 & \bfseries 1234 &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  \\
\hline
& \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] & \bfseries [2] &            &            &            &            &            &            &            & 
\end{tabular}


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! great way to do it but i was hoping to get the color

Comment: you can set hline colous using arrayrulecolor from colortbl and/or hhline packages

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{NiceTabular}{rcccccccc|cccccccc}
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{section 1} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{section 2} \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
&        (1) &        (2) &        (3) &        (4) &        (5) &        (6) &        (7) &        (8) &        (9) &       (10) &       (11) &       (12) &       (13) &       (14) &       (15) &       (16) \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
regression coef 1 &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &             no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no &         no \\
&            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &
                                                                                            &            & &            &            &            &            &            \\
regression coef 2 & \RowStyle{\bfseries}1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 \\
& \RowStyle{\bfseries} [2] & [2] & [2] & [2] & [2] & [2] & [2] & [2] &            &            &            &
&            &            &            & \phantom{noo} \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [red!50!black,rounded corners] (7-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]