# How to draw a filled box with tikz behind the text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, backgrounds

I would like to highlight a certain part of text within a `tabular`. I am using the `tikzmark` command (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/adding-borders-to-an-entire-row-in-a-table)) to remember the coordinates and then afterwards use `tikzpicture` and `draw` to make the filled box, but it is drawn *before* the text and I want it *behind* it.

How do I achieve this ?

This is the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% a marker for endpoints to be used by tikz
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/adding-borders-to-an-entire-row-in-a-table
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{A filled box highlighting something important}
    \begin{tabular}{rcll}
        $\text{p} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & $\text{D} + \text{e}^+ + \nu_e$ & $+\ 0.41\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        $\text{D} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{3}\text{He} + \gamma$ & $+\ 5.51\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\  [1em]
        ${}^{3}\text{He} + {}^{3}\text{He}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{p}$ & $+\  12.98\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        \tikzmark{a}$4\,\text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{e}^+ + 2\,\nu_e$ & $+\  24.8\,\mathrm{MeV}$\tikzmark{b}
    \end{tabular}   

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=1pt, draw=orange!70!black, rounded corners=4pt, fill=gray!20, fill opacity=0.6]
            ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=9pt]a.north) rectangle ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-3pt]b.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the results:
[image]

As you can see, the text in the box is only readable because I set the fill-color to a certain `fill opacity` value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just do the tikz first

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you mean, moving the `tikzpicture` stuff before the `tabular` stuff? But then the marker `a` is not known...? (compilation is not possible, error: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named a is known.'`)

Comment: you had the wrong (original) definition of tikzmark:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You want to draw the tikz first so it comes underneath, the more extended version of tikzmark in the tikz sources handles forward references (giving coordinates a wrong but error free value on the first pass) the library version uses pic coordinates rather than nodes so there are some minor syntax changes but:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% a marker for endpoints to be used by tikz
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/adding-borders-to-an-entire-row-in-a-table
%\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{A filled box highlighting something important}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=1pt, draw=orange!70!black, rounded corners=4pt, fill=gray!20, fill opacity=0.6]
            ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=9pt]$(pic cs:a) + (0pt,8pt)$) rectangle ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-3pt]$(pic cs:b)+(0pt,-2pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tabular}{rcll}
        $\text{p} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & $\text{D} + \text{e}^+ + \nu_e$ & $+\ 0.41\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        $\text{D} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{3}\text{He} + \gamma$ & $+\ 5.51\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\  [1em]
        ${}^{3}\text{He} + {}^{3}\text{He}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{p}$ & $+\  12.98\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        \tikzmark{a}$4\,\text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{e}^+ + 2\,\nu_e$ & $+\  24.8\,\mathrm{MeV}$\tikzmark{b}
    \end{tabular}   


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: aha, there is an updated version of `tikzmark`, wasn't aware of that, thanks a lot! (Now I need to have a close look at the slightly changed syntax to fully understand what is going on.)

Comment: What is the difference between using `xshift`/`yshift` and adding absolute values as in `$(pic cs:a) + (opt,8pt)$`? Sorry, might be obvious but I am not using TikZ on a regular basis.

Comment: @Johnson I know nothing:-) better to ask a question so it is seen by more people who could answer

Answer (score 3):

Don't use gray as a fill colour, but black of a lower opacity.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% a marker for endpoints to be used by tikz
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/adding-borders-to-an-entire-row-in-a-table
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{A filled box highlighting something important}
    \begin{tabular}{rcll}
        $\text{p} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & $\text{D} + \text{e}^+ + \nu_e$ & $+\ 0.41\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        $\text{D} + \text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{3}\text{He} + \gamma$ & $+\ 5.51\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\  [1em]
        ${}^{3}\text{He} + {}^{3}\text{He}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{p}$ & $+\  12.98\,\mathrm{MeV}$\\[1em]
        \tikzmark{a}$4\,\text{p}$ & $\rightarrow$ & ${}^{4}\text{He} + 2\,\text{e}^+ + 2\,\nu_e$ & $+\  24.8\,\mathrm{MeV}$\tikzmark{b}
    \end{tabular}   

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[line width=1pt, draw=orange!70!black, rounded corners=4pt, fill=black, fill opacity=0.1]
            ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=9pt]a.north) rectangle ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-3pt]b.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that works, but it is more a "hack" than a real solution for my problem :)

Comment: @Alf I don't consider this a hack. You can replace black with every other pure colour and choosing a suitable opacity mix every colour you want.

Comment: maybe *hack* was a bit harsh, but it is still before/in front of the text (but you are, of course, correct, I could come up with a opacity-color-mix to get what I want)

Comment: @Alf there is a (not hacky) solution in this recent post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629644/fill-and-overlay-do-not-work-well-together

Comment: @BlackMild interesting! Thanks for pointing me to that solution.